# Moving every string in a list with a specific first word to another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to write Go Fish in Python. I'm writing a function that allows the user to input a card name and then moves every card of that type from the computers hand into the players hand. consider this code:

```
def ask_computer_for_card(player_hand, computer_hand):
    choice = "7"

    for card in computer_hand:
        card_split = card.split()

        if card_split[0] == choice:
            player_hand.append(card)
            computer_hand.remove(card)


computer_hand = ["7 of Hearts", "7 of Spades", "4 of Diamonds"]
player_hand = []

ask_computer_for_card(player_hand, computer_hand
```

I would expect this code to add both "7 of Hearts" and "7 of Spades" to player_hand. However, it only seems to be adding the first "7" item that it encounters in the list. Any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are modifying computer_hand, which you are iterating over. Instead, iterate over a copy of computer_hand, like so:

```
for card in computer_hand[:]:
```

Link to working code: http://ideone.com/dBKUwD